# how to display a random row from a table in android

Tags: android

i have to select a random row from a table and display it on buttons and textview... what i am using it .....

Cursor result=sqldb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM quiztable ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",null );

```
            String ques=result.getString(1);
            String op1=result.getString(2);
            String op2=result.getString(3);
            String op3=result.getString(4);
            String ans=result.getString(5);
            txt17.setText(ques);
            btn10.setText(op1);
            btn11.setText(op2);
            btn12.setText(op3);
```

but the record is not displayed.... i tried try and catch block and display the error using toast .... its say "index -1 requested,with a size 1"

Whts the error in the code?? can any1 tell the solution for it??

thank you in advance ....

Comment: hi everyone,i dun know y am not able to ask ques on this website... so i m asking here........i have made a quiz project using android that is working successfully on eclipse i.e on my pc but as i transfer the apk file in my cell, the pages that works with the database tables are not running and showing a force close....
is there something i am forgeting to include in my project or something
else need to be     transfer along with the .apk file into the cell?????`
thanku in advance..... plz help me ........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not moving the cursor on before you take the items from it.

Before the line

```
 String ques=result.getString(1);
```

Try calling:

```
result.moveToFirst();
```

The cursor always defaults to position -1, the one before the first record. Both `moveToFirst();` or `moveToNext();` will get you to the first record.

Comment: thanx.... nw i got ma mistake n code is working correctly .... thank you 

just 1 one more ques is there any way to compare a column value from database to a button text?? the column value is in string.... i do not find any way of comparing these two??


i have fetch the column value by:-

 String ans=result.getString(5);

"ans" variable contain that value bt how cn i compare it with button text??
any solution for it??

Comment: if (button.getText().toString().equals(ans)){ // is the same } else { // is different }